# Styling scrollbar only for div, not for entire body

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I'm working on my personal portfolio website and I have a problem with styling scrollbar. When I change it for entire body, it works perfectly, but when I want to style it only for scrollable content section (navbar is sticked to the top), everything crashes and I can't even scroll the content. I also wanted scrollbar-track to be transparent but it didn't work either.

```
/* Scrollbar */

.content::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 10px;
}

.content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    background-color: rgba(83, 83, 83, 0.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover
{
    background-color: rgba(83, 83, 83, 1);
}
```

[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/predo/pen/MqEoPm/)

Comment: Do you want to fixed nav header?

Comment: Yes. I want header to be sticked to the top all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the content height. Just add content height, you will see scrollbar.

```
.content{
    height:300px; //for example.
}
```

Comment: See the example .. You might need data inside the content div to show the scrollbars..https://jsfiddle.net/oaecguw0/

Comment: Ok, that's something! Thanks! I have one more question, how can I make scrollbar-track transparent?

Comment: You can use transparent png image.. and add it to css.

.content::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:start {
    background: transparent url('images/transparent-scrollbar.png') repeat-y !important;
}

.content::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:end {
    background: transparent url('images/transparent-scrollbar.png') repeat-y !important;
}

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I didn't saw a scrollbar even when I added some data.

Comment: have you added .content height? can you share the codepen?

Comment: Nice. If you make the height 300px or 500px, you will see the scrollbar.. You are not seeing the scrollbar because content is not going out of the 3000px;. I hope you understand